# Trying to find specific words from all files in a directory using python

Tags: python

I have almost 200 files in a directory and I am looking for specific 
words such as `username`, `pin`, and `schema` in these 200 files.
The question is how can I improve the below script to look for the words from all the files in the directory. My current script can search for words from only one file and add line numbers.
Below is my script:

```
from os import system, listdir,path
import time
system("cls")
system("color b9")
with open("C:\Users\ilan\Desktop\kobi.txt") as filee:
for line in filee:
    for word in line.split():
        if word.lower() =="user" or word.lower()=="password" or word.lower()=="username" or word.lower()=="pass" or word.lower()=="secret" or word.lower()=="key" or word.lower()=="backdoor" or word.lower()=="ip":
                FILE=open("CodeR.txt","a")
                FILE.write(word + "\n" )
                #count =1
                #FILE.write(str(count)+word + "\n" )
                #count+=1
                FILE.close()
```

Comment: I don't see a question in here...

Comment: the question is how can i improve this script to look from all files in the directory and not only 1

Comment: you import `listdir` - use it.

Comment: btw: use `word = word.lower()` and you will not need to use `lower()` in `if` so many times. Or use `if word.lower() in ("user", "password", ...):`

Answer (score 2):

Use `os.walk` to traverse all files in a directory tree.
Use regular expressions (the `re` module) to search for words in a text.

```
import os
import re

words = ['password', 'user', 'ip', 'key']
rx = re.compile('|'.join(words))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\Users\\ilan\Desktop'):
    for filename in files:
        with open(filename) as df:
            data = df.read()
        for match in rx.finditer(data):
            # Use the MatchObject as you like
            print match.span()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script as it is won't work until you take care of a couple of syntax errors.
Here's what's needed to make it work:

1. Python treats backslash characters ("\") specially (as in "\n").
   If you want/need to use a backslash character in a string, you can either:

   A. "escape" each backslash character by doubling it, as in:

   ```
      with open("C:\\Users\\ilan\Desktop\\kobi.txt") as filee:
   ```

   This tells Python that you really want a backslash character.

   OR

   B. Turn your string into a "raw string" by preceding it with 'r', as in:

   ```
      with open(r"C:\Users\ilan\Desktop\kobi.txt") as filee:
   ```
2. Indent the entire "for line in filee" block.

That will turn your code into:

```
from os import system, listdir,path
import time
system("cls")
system("color b9")
with open("C:\\Users\\ilan\Desktop\\kobi.txt") as filee:
    for line in filee:
        for word in line.split():
            if word.lower() =="user" or word.lower()=="password" or word.lower()=="username" or word.lower()=="pass" or word.lower()=="secret" or word.lower()=="key" or word.lower()=="backdoor" or word.lower()=="ip":
                    FILE=open("CodeR.txt","a")
                    FILE.write(word + "\n" )
                    #count =1
                    #FILE.write(str(count)+word + "\n" )
                    #count+=1
                    FILE.close()
```

That can be simplified somewhat by:

1. Removing the:

   ```
   import time
   ```

   since it's not needed.
2. Also, as furas suggests, you can eliminate the need to use lower() so many times by using:

   word = word.lower()

However, what I'd suggest instead is converting the entire line you read in into lowercase.

That will turn your code into:

```
from os import system, listdir,path
system("cls")
system("color b9")
with open("C:\\Users\\ilan\Desktop\\kobi.txt") as filee:
    for line in filee:
        for word in line.lower().split():
            if word =="user" or word=="password" or word=="username" or word=="pass" or word=="secret" or word=="key" or word=="backdoor" or word=="ip":
                    FILE=open("CodeR.txt","a")
                    FILE.write(word + "\n" )
                    #count =1
                    #FILE.write(str(count)+word + "\n" )
                    #count+=1
                    FILE.close()
```

Then, to then change that code so that it works for all of the files in your 'Desktop' diretory, you can use 'os.listdir', as suggested by furas.
Doing that along with some other cleanup (moving your FILE.open() and FILE.close() outside of any of the indented blocks AND putting all of your words into a 'set' which you can check for membership in) gives:

```
from os import system, listdir,path
system("cls")
system("color b9")
FILE=open("CodeR.txt","a")
for fn in listdir("C:\\Users\\ilan\Desktop"):
    with open("C:\\Users\\ilan\Desktop\\" + fn) as filee:
        for line in filee:
            for word in line.lower().split():
                if word in {"user", "password", "username", "pass", "secret", "key", "backdoor", "ip"}:
                        FILE.write(word + "\n" )
                        #count =1
                        #FILE.write(str(count)+word + "\n" )
                        #count+=1
FILE.close()
```

(Otherwise, you're opening and closing FILE repeatably.)

Finally, if your 'Desktop' directory contains any folders, you can exclude them from being read as a normal file (and crashing your script), using the os.path.isfile() function.
And you can use os.path.join() to combine various parts of a path with a filename (letting the os add any needed forward or backward slashes). 
That, along with some changes in spacing, etc. to be more "standard" (according to what the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide expects), gives:

```
from os import system, listdir, path
system("cls")
system("color b9")
FILE = open("CodeR.txt", "a")
desktop_dir = r"C:\Users\ilan\Desktop"
for fn in listdir(desktop_dir):
    fn_w_path = path.join(desktop_dir, fn)
    if path.isfile(fn_w_path):
        with open(fn_w_path) as filee:
            for line in filee:
                for word in line.lower().split():
                    if word in {"user", "password", "username", "pass",
                                "secret", "key", "backdoor", "ip"}:
                        FILE.write(word + "\n")
FILE.close()
```

Comment: It looks like Roland Smith's alternate solution (below) is technically superior to mine. However, it might not be as easy for someone who's relatively inexperienced with Python to understand.