# Search for entire folder rather than a file python

Tags: python

How can I search from entire folder rather than a simple file?

```
#Code Review By 
from os import system, listdir,path
import time
system("cls")
system("color b9")
myList = ["password","user","backdoor","key","ip"]
count =1
path="."
dirs=listdir(path)
with open("C:\Users\ilan\Desktop\kobi.txt") as filee:
    for i, line in enumerate(filee):
        for word in line.split():
            if word.lower() in myList:
                FILE=open("CodeR.txt","a")
                FILE.write("Word \"{}\"was found in line {}".format(myList, i+1)+"\n")
                count+=1
                FILE.close()
```

Comment: This question is very unclear. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to search all of the files in `C:\Users\ilan\Desktop\` for your keywords?

Answer (score 0):

This question appears to be essentially a duplicate of [Trying to find specific words from all files in a directory using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181082/trying-to-find-specific-words-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-python).

On that post, I had tried to show step-by-step how to change the code there into something which would do what was asked.

So, here, I'll just show my final solution:

```
from os import system, listdir, path
system("cls")
system("color b9")
FILE = open("CodeR.txt", "a")
desktop_dir = r"C:\Users\ilan\Desktop"
for fn in listdir(desktop_dir):
    fn_w_path = path.join(desktop_dir, fn)
    if path.isfile(fn_w_path):
        with open(fn_w_path) as filee:
            for line in filee:
                for word in line.lower().split():
                    if word in {"user", "password", "username", "pass",
                                "secret", "key", "backdoor", "ip"}:
                        FILE.write(word + "\n")
FILE.close()
```

and refer any readers to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181082/trying-to-find-specific-words-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-python/35187791#35187791) on the other post for more information/explanation.

~ Russell

P.S. - [Roland Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219295/roland-smith) provided an [alternate solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181082/trying-to-find-specific-words-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-python/35188365#35188365) to the other post, which appears technically superior to mine. However, it might not be as easy for someone who's relatively inexperienced with Python to understand.